# Tikz: Problem with Standalone

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

I have difficulty in using standalone package along with TikZ.

I have the following standalone file: `l1NormInAction.tex`

---

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick, ->] (-1.5,0)--(3,0);
\draw [thick, ->] (0,-1.5)--(0,2);
\draw[blue,dashed, thick] (-1,0)--(0,1)--(1,0)--(0,-1)--cycle;
\node[above right] at (0,1) {$\hat{\mathbf{x}}$};
\node[below left] at (0,0) {$\mathbf{x}$};
\draw[<->,shorten <=-1cm, shorten >=-3mm,thick] (0,1)--(2,0) node [right, above] {$\mathbf{D}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

_________________________________________________________________
```

Using standalone package I used the following code in my document.

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includestandalone[width=.8\textwidth]{figures/l1NormInAction}
\end{figure}
```

The output is attached here. This is not in the expected format and it contains some strange number. Where am I going wrong?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce the problem. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: My Tex version is TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian). Please see my comment for Andrew's answer.

Answer (score 1):

For me this works fine, producing the image:

[image]

You didn't say what your main tex file looks like, so perhaps that's the problem? I used:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includestandalone[width=.8\textwidth]{f}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

(I renamed your standaline file to `f.tex`.)

If you are still having problems then post a full MWE.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I could also compile the minimum version you provided. But my original code is very lengthy and I may not be able to provide it here. But I think, the numbers printed on the left side of the figure has some information about the error. Any clue in that direction?

Comment: @Sooraj The numbers are likely to be `tikz` dimensions, but they could be anything. As your "code is lengthy" I suggest that you try selectively commenting out things until you can isolate what is causing the problem.